# background-image url not showing in iframe

Tags: css, iframe, background-image

I have an iframe that has a background image in a div. The image displays fine with a direct link to the iframe page but when the page is displayed as an iframe (within another page) the image is not visible?

I have checked the code in Firebug and when I hover over the url in the console it just says "failed to load the given URL").

```
.fd-img{background-image:url('images/fd-img.jpg'); width: 342px; height: 228px; margin: 76px 0 0 205px;}

<div class="fd-img"></div>
```

For some reason the image displays in the iframe with no problem using an absolute url but not a relative one. I would use absolute but it is not practical at all for what I need to do.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

in `css`, point `url` link as if you were in the folder where the .css file is located

---

iframe's src will point to a page. The `src` can be set with javascript or however you like, based on event, etc. The `<iframe></iframe>` itself can't have a background image. You can give it dimensions, ie. width, height, scroll, etc. But content is from a source page.

Comment: The css is currently in the same file (not external). Once I have finished the page I will move it externally. The link is working fine as the image displays no problem until it is displayed in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but it appears that AMPPS was the problem. I moved the exact same files to the server and everything worked fine. I was working on my local drive using AMPPS. Nothing has changed server side, I am still using Firefox and the same code so perhaps AMPPS does not like iframes? Hope this helps someone else that is having the same problem.